# How create Get method with path variable and field value other than id ? (Spring Jpa Hibernate Rest)

Tags: java, spring, rest

How create custom method get with path variable which is not id?

```
public class cart {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int Id;

    private int user_id;

    private Date date;
}
```

```
public interface cartRepo extends JpaRepository<cart, Integer>{

    public cart findByUserId(int user_id);
}
```

```
@GetMapping("/cartuser/{user_id}")
    public cart getCartofUser(@Valid @PathVariable int user_id)
    {
        cart cart = _cartRepo.findByUserId(user_id);

        return cart;
    }
```

I try this but doesnt work...

Comment: Please provide some information about your problem. What doesn't work for you and what are you trying to achieve. This is missing information

Comment: I trying to create get method which find data with path variable other than id, in this case find by user_id. Look at cart class...

Comment: Please don't add things like "SOLVED" to the title. Instead, accept the answer you found most useful, or post your own answer and accept that after the timeout.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ok.

Answer (score 1):

Not really get what is the problem you are facing. One thing you can check is the "getCartofUser" function. As your user_id field is int so you can change

```
@PathVariable int user_id
```

to

```
@PathVariable("user_id") Integer user_id
```

(This is used when method parameters type not string. Spring automatically convert to its relevant type like int, String etc.)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

```
public interface cartRepo extends JpaRepository<cart, Integer>{

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE user_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    public cart findByUserId(Integer user_id);
}
```

```
@GetMapping("/cartuser/{user_id}")
    public cart getCartofUser(@Valid @PathVariable("user_id") Integer user_id)
    {
        cart cart = _cartRepo.findByUserId(user_id);

        return cart;
    }
```